# setup and draw with canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

How can I do everything I do with the functions `setup()` and `draw()` but while using Canvas tags?

Because when I try to set up a canvas while having a canvas tag present it just creates a second canvas.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to use P5.js with an existing canvas element on your page, instead of creating a new one using the `createCanvas()` function.

I don't know of a way to do that, but you can position the canvas created by P5.js using the `parent()` function. You can read more info in the [P5.dom reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom) or [the wiki](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Beyond-the-canvas), and here's a simple example:

In your HTML you would have something like this:

```
<div id='myContainer'></div>
```

And then you could insert your canvas into that div using the `parent()` function:

```
function setup() {
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(600, 400);
  myCanvas.parent('myContainer');
}
```

Note that this requires the P5.dom library in addition to P5.js. P5.dom also includes functions for dealing with CSS and styling.